# How to Open .ipynb notebook on Colab

Tags: julia, google-colaboratory

**strong text**I want to open the file "Julia on Colab_1.2.ipynb"

Nevertheless, when I try to upload the file "Julia on Colab_1.2.ipynb", the documents do not show available to upload(Image attached)

[image: The file can not be uploaded with Colab]

However, in the Tutorial, it is shown that it is possible to open.

I created the file "Julia on Colab_1.2.ipynb", on TextEdit and I saved it as an "enriched text document."

Why can I not open this notebook created on TextEdit?

I create this file following the [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpZo3L2dYTY)

[image: Type of the file "Julia on Colab_1.2.ipynb"]